If $(f_n)$ is uniformly limited, $f_n\rightarrow_u f$, $(g_n)$ is equicontinuous, $g_n\rightarrow_u g$, then $g_n\circ f_n\rightarrow_u g\circ f$
Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be sequences. Suppose that:
$(i)$ $(f_n)_n$ is uniformly limited and $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly, for a certain $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$;
$(ii)$ $(g_n)_n$ is equicontinuous and $g_n\rightarrow g$ uniformly, for a certain $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
Show that $g_n\circ f_n\rightarrow g\circ f$ uniformly

My attempt:
$|f_n(x)|\leq M\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$
Let $K:=[-M,M]$
Let $\mathcal{X}:=\{g_n|_{K}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq C(K;\mathbb{R})$
$\mathcal{X}$ is equicontinuous
Since $K$ is compact and $g$ is continuous, we have that $g|_{K}$ reaches a maximum and a minimum in $K$
Let $N:=\max\{|\max g(K)|,|\min g(K)|\}$
Let $A_n:=\max\{|\max g_n(K)|,|\min g_n(K)|\}$
Given $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $n_0$ such that $n>n_0\Rightarrow |A_n-N|<\varepsilon$, beacuse $g_n\rightarrow g$ uniformly
Then, $(A_n)_n$ is limited
Let $A:=\max\{N,\max_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n\}$,
Then, $\mathcal{X}(x)\leq A\,\forall x\in K$
$\mathcal{X}$ is equicontinuous and uniformly bounded, then $\{g_n\circ f_n(x):n\in\mathbb{N},x\in\mathbb{R}^m\}\subseteq\{g_n(x):n\in\mathbb{N},x\in K\}=\mathcal{X}$ is equicontinuous and uniformly bounded
Therefore, by Arzelà-Ascoli theorem, $(g_n\circ f_n)_n$ has a subsequence $(g_{n_k}\circ f_{n_k})_k$ that converges uniformly
Since $g_n\circ f_n\rightarrow g\circ f$, $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly and $g_n\rightarrow g$ uniformly, the sequence $(g_n\circ f_n)_n$ must be one of the possible uniformly convergent subsequences

The part where I have doubts is the last line. To be honest, I got stuck in the previous line, then I just made up the last line beacause $I)$ it is the result I need, and $II)$ it makes a bit of sense intuitively, but I don't know if it is correct, and if it is, I don't know why

You can just prove this by definition.
For any $\varepsilon>0$, choose $N_1$ s.t.
$$\sup|g_n(y)-g(y)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2},\forall n>N_1$$
By equi-continuity, we can choose $\delta >0$ s.t.
$$|g_n(y_1)-g_n(y_2)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2},\forall |y_1-y_2|<\delta,\forall n$$
By uniformal convergence of $f_n$, we can choose $N_2$ s.t.
$$\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\delta,\forall n>N_2$$
Then for all $n>\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, we have
$$|g_n(f_n(x))-g(f(x))|\leq |g_n(f_n(x))-g_n(f(x))|+|g_n(f(x))-g(f(x))|\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon$$
